# Batch Renaming PDFs using content from document on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I have 7000 pdf docs in folder "ffl" they all have been through ocr program so contents can be copy and pasted.

Each document contains text "license *-**-***-**-**-*****"
The number is 15 digits long has dashes and the 10th item is a letter.

Need a batch to rename all files by the license number in the document.

Is there a script I can run to accomplish this? Have been searching for about a week. Everything is talking about the new way to rename from finder. Nothing on renaming from contents of doc.  Pretty new to terminal.

I have seen the basic command for renaming 
mv "old location" "new location"

mv /home/user/my_static /home/user/static

Right now I copy the number and paste as file name. Need a faster way.

Please and thank you for any advise.

Comment: Please give us an example license file/document so we can work on it.

Comment: Sure http://www.birminghampistol.com/images/9-91-053-01-4L-04292.pdf  is a link to a sample file.  would need to rename it 9-91-053-01-4L-04292.pdf

Comment: sample folder location /Users/caradcp/Dropbox/FFLDatabase/abbyy

Comment: I have posted an answer, please mark as a correct answer if it's solving your problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please install pip:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

or

```
brew install python
```

Secondly install pdfminer:

```
pip install pdfminer
```

By using pdfminer and standard libraries of Python I have created a script that specific to your problem:

**rename.py**

```
import commands
import re
import glob, os

os.chdir(".") # In this directory
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"): # For all files with extension .pdf

    pdf_text = commands.getstatusoutput('pdf2txt.py ' + file)[1] # Get text content of the pdf file

    result = re.search('[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', pdf_text) # Search using a regex specific to your solution and find the license number

    if result: # If license number has been found
        command = 'mv ' + file + ' ' + result.group(0) + '.pdf'
        commands.getstatusoutput(command) # Rename file to LICENSE_NUMBER.pdf
        print command + ' :: Command executed.' # Show what command has been executed
```

You can execute it by simply typing `python rename.py`.

This Python script will search the directory(*same directory with itself*) for files with **.pdf** extension.

Then it will search each file for the license numbers according to a regular expression that I wrote for you.

Lastly, if there is a result it will change file's name to *LICENSE_NUMBER*.pdf

**Addition upon OP's comment:**

If some other PDF documents have a little bit different formatting and this script is not working for them, simply investigate the text contents with:

```
commands.getstatusoutput('pdf2txt.py ' + file)
```

For your sample file it was:

```
...ct ATI- \nCorrespondence To\n\nLicense\nNumber\n\n9-91-053-01-4L-04292\n\nA IF  - Chief. FF...
```

So I have created a regex to find substring `\n\nLicense\nNumber\n\n9-91-053-01-4L-04292\n\nA` and get License Number from it. Maybe you can create a more tolerant/general regex for your PDF documents by investigating more samples.

Comment: OP's environment is a mac. Does apt exist on Mac?

Comment: @kometen Sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: Maybe pdfminer can be installed using macports or homebrev, or manually. Script will still work. :-)

Comment: @mertyildiran. This worked perfectly for the sample file.  It also worked on about 5 out of 100 of my test pdfs. What can I do to make it work for the other files?    They files vary in quality.  I have been searching for edits to this part of the text  "result = re.search('License\nNumber\n\n(.+?)\n\nA', pdf_text) # Search using a regex specific to your solution and find the license number"  I just don't much about this language.  I'm so grateful for your help. Thanks

Comment: @Planterguy If all the PDF files don't have the exact same formatting, it's impossible to achieve this task with a single version of regex. Just look for the License Number in pdf_text variable by printing it: `print pdf_text` And create a different version of regex. Regex standard is language independent. Maybe there could be a general pattern for all of your PDF documents but I don't know, I need to see other versions.

Comment: @Planterguy I have also made some additions to my answer, please take a look.

Comment: The only standard I can find is the format of the license number. "[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" 
Here are 8 examples after pulling the data
1. ....' K 
9-99-001-01-7A-00695 
Jan...

2...v>"- 
1^59^ 03-011:5F-02735 
f r u n ..

3…cense 
1-64-121 -01-7E-00581 
May…

4…ense
1-64-121 -01-7E-00581 
May..

5….ber: 
5-43-031-01-7C-0507G 
14…

6…ate
4-35-081 -01-6C-00245 
Mar…

7…CES
4-31-163-01 6A 14064…

8….14
6-05-003-01 -5L-00790 
N…

Is it possible to write a something to find that?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Planterguy Yeah, your Regex is much better than mine. I have updated my answer with using your Regex. Now it's working perfectly! :)

Comment: Best one yet! Thank you. It worked on the majority of the the files. They are some where the OCR didn't process correctly but that doesn't have anything to do with the script. If the doc was in good enough condition the script worked. Thank you for the help. @Mark Setchell thanks for figuring out the Regex

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, I think we can do a bit better now I understand the format of the number better...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Don't barf if no files, or if upper or lower case names
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

for f in *.pdf; do
    lic=$(pdfgrep "[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" "$f" | grep -oE "[0-9-]+[A-Z][0-9-]+")
    # Check licence is at least 15 characters, else do nothing
    if [ ${#lic} -gt 15 ]; then
       echo mv "$f" "${lic}.pdf"
    fi
done
```

If it takes forever, you could also use `homebrew` to install **GNU Parallel** so you can do them all in parallel and get the job done faster. So, you would install with:

```
brew install parallel
```

and then change the script to do just a single file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo Usage: Renamer file
   exit 1
fi
f="$1"
lic=$(pdfgrep "[0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" "$f" | grep -oE "[0-9-]+[A-Z][0-9-]+")
# Check licence is at least 15 characters, else do nothing
if [ ${#lic} -gt 15 ]; then
   echo mv "$f" "${lic}.pdf"
fi
```

Then you can get them all done with:

```
parallel ./Renamer ::: *.pdf
```

### Option 1

You can extract the license number using `pdfgrep`, which you can install using `homebrew`. You would need to go to [the homebrew wesbite](http://brew.sh) and copy the one-liner from there (which I don't want to put here in case it gets outdated) and paste it into Terminal and run it. Then you can install `pdfgrep` with:

```
brew install pdfgrep
```

Alternatively, you can download, and build `pdfgrep` yourself if you like doing that sort of thing! [Download](https://pdfgrep.org).

You can then extract the licence from a PDF file with:

```
pdfgrep -i "License Number" SomeFile.pdf | grep -oE "[0-9-]+[A-Z][0-9-]+"
```

and put that in a variable with:

```
lic=$(pdfgrep -i "License Number" SomeFile.pdf | grep -oE "[0-9-]+[A-Z][0-9-]+")
```

So, if you have 7,000 PDF files in a directory you would need to go that directory and save the following as a script called `NameByLicence`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Don't barf if no files, or if upper or lower case names
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob

for f in *.pdf; do
    lic=$(pdfgrep -i "License Number" "$f" | grep -oE "[0-9-]+[A-Z][0-9-]+")
    # Check licence is at least 15 characters, else do nothing
    if [ ${#lic} -gt 15 ]; then
       echo mv "$f" "${lic}.pdf"
    fi
done
```

Once you have saved the script, make it executable (just necessary once) with:

```
chmod +x NameByLicence
```

Then you can run it with:

```
./NameByLicence
```

**PLEASE MAKE A BACKUP FIRST AND TEST ON A FEW DUMMY FILES**

If it looks correct, remove the word `echo` and it will actually do the name changes - at the moment it just tells you what it would do, rather than doing anything.

### Option 2

If you don't want to use `homebrew` and `pdfgrep`, you *can* do it with native OSX tools, but it is a bit harder. Basically, you make an Automator workflow to extract the text from your PDF into a temporary text document and then you convert that from UTF-16 into ASCII and `grep` in there. If that makes sense to you, here are the steps:

Make an Automator workflow that looks like this:

[image]

You get `/tmp` in the *"Save Output to"* field by using SHIFT+COMMAND+G and typing `/tmp`. Check the **Replace Existing Files** box so that it still works for your second PDF when the licence from the previous file is there.

Save that as *"as an Application"*, called `pdf2text`. Now you can run the following instead of `pdfgrep`:

```
./pdf2text.app/Contents/MacOS/"Application Stub" SomeFile.pdf
```

and it will extract the text to `/tmp/licence.txt`. But you are not done yet, because that is UTF-16, so, to search in the file, you need:

```
iconv -c -f UTF-16 -t ASCII /tmp/licence.txt | grep -oE "[0-9A-Z-]{17,}" 
9-91-053-01-4L-04292
```

So, now you need to put that inside the `for` loop in the little `bash` script above.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did option 1. ran it against 200 files. It work on about 15. Some created partial file name results.  The documents vary in quality.  Here are a few more samples. http://www.birminghampistol.com/images/21pdf.zip  The only thing that doesn't vary is the license number 5-75-353-01-7A-09283  digit-digitdigit-digitdigitdigit-digitdigit-digitletter-digitdigitdigitdigitdigit   It is all digits except the ten spot. Thanks

Comment: @Planterguy Ok, I think we can do a bit better now I understand the format of the number better... please have another look!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to rename a bunch of pdf files with content extracted from the pdf file (in that case a date). I tried at first to do a bash only with pdfgrep, but the brew install exploded on me (seems like the formula is not updated).

What worked for me is Automator to extract the pdf content to text, and then a quick and dirty script to extract the  text and rename. See attached screenshot of the Automator action:

- first part cleans up the temp directory (in my case copying the pdfs into "renaming_pdfs"
- extract the text into rtf
- script grabs the text that I want to rename the file to (in this case the content of the line follow "US4") and renames the files

[image]